# How to count blank row of excel from given range using c#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to get the row count of rows which don't have any value (any of columns)

Sample image of the Excel file I'm using:  [image: My excel file that I'm using]

Highlighted rows have some values in some columns rest of rows are blank I need to count those rows.
I already used this method

```
int blankRows = 0;
double notEmpty = 1;
while (notEmpty > 0)
{
    string aCellAddress = "A" + (rowIndex++).ToString();
    Excel.Range row = excelApp.get_Range(aCellAddress, aCellAddress).EntireRow;
    notEmpty = excelApp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(row);
    if (notEmpty <= 0)
    {
        blankRows++;
    }
}
```

but this is very time consuming process when file is large and minimum number of blank rows is there.

Answer (score -1):

One thing that might help would be to find the last column that has data and last row that has data as to limit your search.

This is VBA code snippet, but could be easily transformed to C#:

```
'iterate through columns to determine which is longest to determine the highest row number.
    For i = 1 To 16384 'number of columns in excel
        'get the row
        rowcount = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
        'check to see if it's larger than what it is now, if it is, set the value of lRow.
        If rowcount > lrow Then
            lrow = rowcount
        End If
    Next
```

then use a similar loop to get the last row based on the last row, stepping through each row until the last one to get the last column with data.

You can use those values to limit the range that you're looking through. I'm not sure if it will be any faster, but it might help.

Comment: hello that all i know, i want to find blank rows count without iterating row vise loop.